# python connectvity of mysql with csv

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, csv

"text" and "imdburl" columns are common in all tables
but "year" is only present in one table when i add year it says unknown column "year"
can anyone tell me how can i first check if this column exist in table then add its add otherwise just display N\A

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
conn=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db="bulk")
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("show tables")
myresult=cursor.fetchall()
for i in myresult:
     print(i)
     query=('select  text,imdburl from %s '%(i))
     cursor.execute(query)
     result=cursor.fetchall()
     print(result)
     my=pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
     my.to_csv("new.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: information_schema.columns table has the names of the columns from all tables. However, if you want to dump all fields, then just use select * from tablename.

Comment: @Shadow Can u please tell where to write it

Comment: Well, you need to do the check before the select query.

Comment: you should not write queries like that or you will make yourself target to sql injection

Comment: @CyrilJouve how else should i write 

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you only have a single table that needs the year column, so assuming that `yeartable` would be the name of that table

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
conn=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db="bulk")
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("show tables")
myresult=cursor.fetchall()
for i in myresult:
     print(i)
     if (i == 'yeartable'):
         query=('select text, imdburl, year from %s '%(i))
     else:
         query=('select text,imdburl from %s '%(i))
     cursor.execute(query)
     result=cursor.fetchall()
     print(result)
     my=pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
     my.to_csv("new.csv",index=False)
```

For a scalable solution you need to get some information on the table 
You can fetch all column names of a table like this:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

check for a column named `year` in the `if` from above instead of checking for `yeartable` and you should be good

Comment: Actually i have specific column which i have to export  ,these are only 3 columns which i have to export

Comment: @Robin do you know the name of the table with the year column?

Comment: i know but what if in future i have to add more table to the database

Comment: @Robin in that case you will need to obtain some information from the database beforehand. Just notice that database operations are normally rather costly so if you are only having a few of these special cases you might be better off with storing them in a setting

Answer (score 0):

This runs under python 3.8.5
And it encloses the second query in a try except in case has no year column then it rins the query with outyear..

you should think about calling the different csvs, if there more than one also differently

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
conn=pymysql.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="testpawwd",db="bulkb1")
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'bulk'")
myresult=cursor.fetchall()
for i in myresult:
    print(i)
    query=('select  text, imdburl, `year` from %s '%(i))
    query2=('select  text, imdburl from %s '%(i))
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result=cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        my=pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
        my.to_csv("new%s.csv"%(i),index=False)
        break
    except:
        try:
            cursor.execute(query2)
            result=cursor.fetchall()
            print(result)
            my=pd.read_sql_query(query2,conn)
            my.to_csv("new%s.csv"%(i),index=False)
            break
        except:
            print("An error occured")
```

Comment: yes, it will run, but my system is running always with all updates installed

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: there was a typo in my code try this again with the changed code

Comment: no no i already corrected it still there was no column of year in csv

Comment: isn't there any kind of command which can help me like(if exist)

Comment: please explain what isn't working and no you coult test it for the xolumn, but that woukd make it much slower and increased the number of threads

Comment: it isnt showing any error but when i check my csv there is no column for year

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp        can this help in anyway?

Comment: no but as i mentioned in the theanswer, you **overwrite new.csv**, with every run you make, so change he name for every table

Comment: I changed my answer again, i reworte the cav names so that they get an individual nam